# не могу импортировать базу данных flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

это main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///user.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    class Users(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        key = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
    @app.route('/login')
    def login():
        return render_template('log-in-form.html')
    @app.route('/signup')
    def signup():
        return render_template('sign-up-form.html')


    app.run()
```

что бы создать базу данных нужно импортировать из main bd.

```
from main import db
```

но выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'main' 
(C:\Users\ANDREY\PycharmProjects\mediaprojectreturn\main.py)
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Если что то сделал не так извиняюсь - первый раз на форуме. Спасибо

Comment: я не понимаю. В гайде он просто ввел команду и у него все получилось, а я уже весь вечер мучаюсь.

Comment: Уберите `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Из под него вы ничего не импортирует. Либо создавайте `db.create_all()` под `__main__`

Comment: щас попробую. Спасибо

Comment: Если запустить Python-файл прямо, то значением __name__ будет __main__. Если же его запустить в качестве модуля, то значением будет уже не __main__, а название модуля.

Comment: я попробова без if. Тут уже другая ошибка. ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'main' (C:\Users\ANDREY\PycharmProjects\mediaprojectreturn\main.py)

Comment: Andy Pavlov хочу спросить как создать db.create_all. Я сейчас пытаюсь импортировать db, что бы это сделать. Я что то неправильно делаю?

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Запуск `app.run()` выносим в
`if __name__ == '__main__':`. Все остальное выносим из под него.

Все, что под строкой [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/11_modules/if_name_main.html) не будет выполняться при импорте. А Вы под него как раз туда все объявление засунули.

Файл `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///user.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    key = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('log-in-form.html')


@app.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return render_template('sign-up-form.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Файл `db_make.py`

```
from main import db

db.create_all()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось))

Comment: Прочтите на досуге https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/11_modules/if_name_main.html